# Faking contacts for screenshots

Tags: android, google-play

Are there any easy way to load fake contacts in your phone, so that you can take screenshots and videos of your app?

One idea would be to create a new Google Account with fake contacts, but I don't think there is a way to make your application display the contacts of that account only, without any additional programming involved.

Comment: Export your contacts. Alter the data in the file. Import it into your emulator. Task complete.

Comment: How do you export/import contacts in the emulator? That might be okay for screenshots, but what about videos where in order to showcase something you need to 'touch' instead of mouse over?

Comment: Export from your phone, copy into the DDMS, import in your emulator.

Comment: @AlexStyl You want to show duplicate contact/video right?